# SFML doesn't play any sounds, but no errors

Tags: c++, audio, ubuntu-16.04, sfml

I have a simple c++ programm using SFML to play a .wav sound file. It looks like this:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    if (!buffer.loadFromFile("beep-01a.wav"))
        return -1;

    sf::Sound sound;
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.play();
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;  
    return 0;  
}
```

I'm running it on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and compiling it with

```
$ g++ -c main.cpp
$ g++ main.o -o sfml-app -lsfml-audio
$ ./sfml-app
```

I've installed SFML with apt-get as a package. When I run the ./sfml-app it outputs "Hello World", but I can't hear anything. I've tried turning the volume up, restarting my computer, putting headphones in, etc. When I play the sound file by double clicking it, it plays a beep sound.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be many reasons why no sound is played, even if your code was entirely correct.
However, it isn't, as sf::Sound::play *asynchronously* plays the sound in another thread (as stated [here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sound.php#a2953ffe632536e72e696fd880ced2532)) but your application finishes pretty fast, thus giving the other thread no real chance to play much of the specified sound buffer.
So in order to have at least a theoretical chance of hearing anything, I would suggest to insert some instruction to block the main thread, like

```
std::cin.get();
```

right before exiting.